# "Board" and "go/be aboard/on board" in AE

Tags: word-usage

In AE, is it acceptable to say **board/go aboard** (and hence be aboard/on board) for such miscellaneous and various *vehicular (or mobile) devices* as an elevator, a bus, a truck, a van, a people carrier, a car (auto), a carnival ride, a ski gondola, a toboggan, a sled, a sledge, a canoe, a tractor, an excavator, a baby carriage, a cradle, a crib, a coffin, and a time machine (the type of those featured in the movies *The Time Machine* (1960), and *Time After Time* (1979))?

As far as your variety of English is concerned, is such usage acceptable?

e.g.

*Two of them **boarded the sedan**.*
http://www.abs-cbnnews.com/nation/metro-manila/03/09/13/robbers-kill-french-tourist-precinct-chief-axed

*Atkins said she **boarded the elevator**..."*
http://abclocal.go.com/wls/story?id=9327879

Comment: Yes. It could be used that way, and even if it might sound strange in a particular context, it would be interpreted as a figurative usage. Still, one never *boards* a baby carriage unless one is too old for it anyway.

Comment: Just to add as a comment: If you go to Denver International Airport, there is a train that takes you between terminals. In Terminal C, the last stop on the line, there is an automated message and sign that tells you "no boarding at this position" by one set of tracks.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet -  You've asked 21 questions to date. Have you accepted any of them? Have you upvoted any? This is what I would like to know in return for the times I have answered you.

Comment: @Susan I just did. ;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, the terms "board" or "go aboard" is most commonly used for large public transport or "common carriers" like boats, trains, and airplanes where you are going on a trip with a group of other people. It is especially common with boats since that's the origin of the term. By contrast, you are not usually "aboard" something that you control or drive.

So whether it works for any given other vehicle usually depends on how close it approximates one of those things. For things that are smaller, you're just "on" it or "in" it, depending on whether it is enclosed. For almost all things that you can be "on board", you can also be "on", although for boats it sounds a little informal (but cf. ["I'm On A Boat" by Lonely Island/T-Pain](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7yfISlGLNU&feature=kp)).

Here's my thoughts on your examples and whether one can be "on board" them:

- elevator. Acceptable but not common.
- a bus. Sure, especially if it is a large bus.
- a truck. No.
- a van. No.
- a people carrier. Maybe. I don't hear from people on board people carriers that often.
- a car (auto). No.
- a carnival ride. Maybe if it is large.
- a gondola. Sure, it's a boat.
- a toboggan. No.
- a sled. No.
- a sledge. No.
- a canoe. No. Although it's a boat, you're propelling yourself, and it's just too small to be considered "on board".
- a baby carriage. Only if you're making a joke that the baby carriage is like a boat/train.
- a cradle. No.
- a crib. No.
- a coffin. Definitely not.
- and a time machine. Maybe. Again not something one hears of very often. I think if you have a time machine, the language around them is sufficiently underdeveloped that you could choose whether to be "on" or "on board."

The Philippine Star's usage of "boarded" sounds unusual, but less so given that the people who were "boarding" were not driving. Therefore, there is a sense of conveyance, of being a passenger. You wouldn't see that sentence in the New York Times, though.

The California Court of Appeals, although they could have been more specific, appears to have been describing a situation where the man was physically on top of the car, like on the hood. The preceding sentence is "he jumped in front of [the car] and kicked her windshield out."

Comment: I actually meant a ski gondola. ;) How about a coffin or a cradle on wheels in fictional contexts, can "board" belong here?

Comment: Ski gondola, sure, that works. If you had a fictional coffin or cradle that is operating like a train (i.e., going someplace and the passenger is not controlling it), then yeah, I could see that being "on board".

Answer (score 2):

In AmE, we **board** only planes, trains, buses and ships.

We **get into** elevators, trucks, vans, excavator, cars and canoes.

We **climb into** carnival rides.

We **get on** a toboggan, sled and a tractor.

One **puts** a baby into a car, carriage, cradle, crib, highchair, johnny-jump-up, and, to the dismay of Pediatricians everywhere, walkers.

One is **laid** coffin, is buried and awaits an utterance which will set one to **turning, spinning or rolling over** in one's grave.

We **set foot in/get into/get on/climb into, or board** time machines, depending which type it is.

I don't know what we do with gondolas or sledges; my guess is that we would **look askance** at them and refuse to do anything at all involving them any further.

Comment: As long as you board trains, planes, busses, and ships, you get on them, right? Now, as long as you get on a toboggan, a sled, and a tractor, why then can't you say that you "board" them? As for elevators, I always thought it was typical AE usage to say "get on/off the elevator". ;)

Comment: I thought it also was typical to AE to say "board/get on (board)" for carnival/amusement rides.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet -  You've asked 21 questions to date. Have you accepted any of them? Have you upvoted any? This is what I would like to know in return for the times I have answered you.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker I can say that many of those are correct usage.

But, boarding a sedan sounds funny to my ear.  In AE, one *gets in(to)* a car or sedan.  You don't typically board one.

To my ear, boarding is usually reserved for larger forms of transport:  planes, trains, buses, larger boats, etc.

You wouldn't board a toboggan, baby carriage, canoe, coffin, etc.  Instead those are items you would either *get on* or *get in* depending on the specific usage.